# Search Icon clickable MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to make the search icon clickable so you can search what you have written by also clicking the icon

cant find anything on mui

ive tried to make a button on it but dont know what to do when it comes to onClick

Comment: create a onClick function and log the msg if msg logs correctly the button will clicking correctly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.